# Issuing new token in an ICO, is there any option to transfer some percentage of tokens to some other stellar account?

Tags: token, ico

How can we achieve the following use case in stellar ICO:

- When we issue a custom token and distribute the tokens supply for users to buy.
- For example some user makes a transaction to buys 100 tokens
- Some percentage, let's say 3% of tokens should be transferred to another operational (admin) stellar account

So, if a total of 100 tokens are bought by the users. We want to maintain a stellar account which should hold 3 tokens i.e. 3% of the total tokens sold.

How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 2):

You can perform multiple payments in a single transaction so just create a transaction with one 100 token payment to user and another 3 token payment to admin.